# What is the best way to trim a trailing character in Dart?

Tags: dart

In Dart the `trim()`, `trimLeft()` and `trimRight()` string methods do not take a parameter to specify unwanted non-whitespace characters.

What is the best way to trim a specific character from the ends of a string in Dart?

I am using this for now, but it feels hard to remember and not very generic:

```
final trailing = RegExp(r"/+$");
final trimmed = "test///".replaceAll(trailing, "");
assert(trimmed == "test");
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no specific functionality to trim non-whitespace from the end of a string.
Your `RegExp` based approach is reasonable, but can be dangerous when the character you want to remove is meaningful in a RegExp.

I'd just make my own function:

```
String removeTrailing(String pattern, String from) {
  if (pattern.isEmpty) return from;
  var i = from.length;
  while (from.startsWith(pattern, i - pattern.length)) i -= pattern.length;
  return from.substring(0, i);
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
final trimmed = removeTrailing("/", "test///")
assert(trimmed == "test");
```

The corresponding `trimLeading` function would be:

```
String trimLeading(String pattern, String from) {
  if (pattern.isEmpty) return from;
  var i = 0;
  while (from.startsWith(pattern, i)) i += pattern.length;
  return from.substring(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the existing answer by `lrn` has a lot of problems - including infinite loop scenarios - I thought I'd post my version.

```
String trimLeft(String from, String pattern){
    if( (from??'').isEmpty || (pattern??'').isEmpty || pattern.length>from.length ) return from;

    while( from.startsWith(pattern) ){
        from = from.substring(pattern.length);
    }
    return from;
}

String trimRight(String from, String pattern){
    if( (from??'').isEmpty || (pattern??'').isEmpty || pattern.length>from.length ) return from;

    while( from.endsWith(pattern) ){
        from = from.substring(0, from.length-pattern.length);
    }
    return from;
}

String trim(String from, String pattern){
    return trimLeft(trimRight(from, pattern), pattern);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's better to do it with extension functions.
This code is based on @Magnus answer:

```
extension StringFuncs on String {
  String trimCharLeft(String pattern) {
    if (isEmpty || pattern.isEmpty || pattern.length > length) return this;
    var tmp = this;
    while (tmp.startsWith(pattern)) {
      tmp = substring(pattern.length);
    }
    return tmp;
  }

  String trimCharRight(String pattern) {
    if (isEmpty || pattern.isEmpty || pattern.length > length) return this;
    var tmp = this;
    while (tmp.endsWith(pattern)) {
      tmp = substring(0, length - pattern.length);
    }
    return tmp;
  }

  String trimChar(String pattern) {
    return trimCharLeft(pattern).trimCharRight(pattern);
  }
}
```

Example for using:

```
 yourString.trimChar(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

To trim all trailing/right characters by specified characters, use the method:

```
class StringUtil {

  static String trimLastCharacters(String srcStr, String pattern) {   
    if (srcStr.length > 0) {   
      if (srcStr.endsWith(pattern)) { 
        final v = srcStr.substring(0, srcStr.length - 1 - pattern.length);
        return trimLastCharacters(v, pattern);
      } 
      return srcStr; 
    }   
    return srcStr;
  }

}
```

For example, you want to remove all `0` behind the decimals

```
$23.67890000
```

then, invoke the method

```
StringUtil.trimLastCharacters("$23.67890000", "0")
```

finally, got the output:

```
$23.6789
```